# urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed , how to check validity of url, and simply avoid it by pass if not working

Tags: python, http, parsing, beautifulsoup

It's a problem often ask, as I can see.
I have a program that dig data, in it a list of url.
An other part of the program open from the list each url with Beautiful soup.
It is perfectly working but sometime I get the title error.

```
Exception has occurred: URLError
<urlopen error [Errno 11001] getaddrinfo failed>
```

And the program stop.

Here is part of the code.

```
for i in range (1,len(my_list),1):#len(my_list)
url = my_list[i]

page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

I want just to avoid those not working url, and continue the program.

How to do that I thought it had to do with, try, exception, finally,
but I don't know.

If I am able to find a solution, I will add it here.
But your help will be most welcomed.

Comment: Use try/except block

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you solve it as you already mentioned it with try except?

```
for i in range (1,len(my_list),1):#len(my_list)
    url = my_list[i]

    try:
        page=urllib.request.urlopen(url)
    except URLError as e:
        print(e)
        continue

    soup = BeautifulSoup(page, 'html.parser')
```

Comment: Thanks for the reactivity PhilippSelenium, I did tried but the code was still stopped.

Comment: to PhilippSelenium : I am reviewing all my posts on this site, I found back your Answer, At the time I was blocked, yes...but after sometime, I realised I was making an other mistake, then, after that everything was working like a charm. A great thanks for your Help.

Comment: @Tsurubaso Can you mark it as resolved and accepted then?

Comment: WIth pleasure, will search how do that